# Does a background thread only work when the app in on top in IOS swift?

Tags: swift, multithreading, websocket

I have a websocket server which executed on a background thread like this:

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInteractive).async {
    let server = SecondServer()
    server.run()
}
```

But there is a problem. websocket server only responds to client commands when the app is on top. for example, when I run browser and send websocket command, the server doesn't respond until I bring my app on top. Is there any solution to help me that I can run my server on the background and my app doesn't need to be on top?

Update:

I changed my code to print somthing in console after 1 second, I found out that printing in the console stop as soon as the app goes behind. Maybe I make mistake in how run my thread. Do I choose right code to run my server on the background?

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInteractive).async {
    let server = SecondServer()
    server.run()
}
```

Comment: You run browser means your app is in background?

Comment: thanks for response, I have a websocket server swift app and I send command to server(swift app) by browser. it means browser is client that sends command to server. my app has UI and the socket server is executed on the background of app.

Comment: Did you enable the background service? or your socket remains connected to the server in the background as well?

Comment: I put "DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInteractive).async" in SceneDelegate.swift file and it is executed once. I think browser remain connected to server according my log, but server doesn't recieve any message from browser.

Comment: this is my server code: https://github.com/apple/swift-nio/blob/main/Sources/NIOWebSocketServer/main.swift

Comment: Once the bg task is done (~3 minutes), the application is not allowed for any BG tasks other than enabled capabilities such as music, location etc.

Comment: it doesn't take 3 minutes. the server app can't response to client command as soon as another app goes up (on the server app).

Comment: I am afraid @MohsenGorgani you are asking a wrong question. The DispatchQueue is handling thread(putting away from ui (main) thread), it won't help to keep your TCP connection when the app status is in background.

Comment: thanks @Horst, How can I run my server on the background of my app in different thread?